# href in html can't show the route with angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to learn angularjs.so i create a project with mvc with a simple page that has a `href` link .when the user click on this link the new page should be displayed in the browser.

I create a `layout` as a master page as you can see :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="homeIndex">

    <head>
        <title></title>

    <script src="~/Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>


    </head>
    <body>
        @RenderBody()
        @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)

    </body>

</html>
```

I create a module in `angularjs` called `homeindex` as you can see here :

// home-index.js
var homeIndexModule = angular.module("homeIndex", []);

```
$routeProvider.when("/newmessage", {
    controller: "newTopicController",
    templateUrl: "/templates/newTopicView.html"
});
$routeProvider.otherwise({ redirectTo: "/" });
```

}]);

I have a controller called `home` that has a action `index` the view code is like this :

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/_Shared.cshtml";
}        
@section Scripts {
 <script src="~/js/mapp.js"></script>

}

<div >
    <a href="#/newmessage">Add New Message</a>
  </div>
```

I have a folder called `templates` that include the html page called `newTopicView` but when i click on the `href` link the `newTopicView` does't appear in the browser.why ?

[image]

In console i get this error :

```
Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.8/$injector/modulerr?p0=homeIndex&p1=%5B%24injector%3Aunpr%5D%20http%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.4.8%2F%24injector%2Funpr%3Fp0%3D%2524routeProvider%0AG%2F%3C%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A29188%2FScripts%2Fangular.min.js%3A6%3A416%0Aeb%2Fr.%24injector%3C%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A29188%2FScripts%2Fangular.min.js%3A41%3A121%0Ad%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A29188%2FScripts%2Fangular.min.js%3A39%3A92%0Ae%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A29188%2FScripts%2Fangular.min.js%3A39%3A362%0Ad%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A29188%2FScripts%2Fangular.min.js%3A38%3A56%0Ag%2F%3C%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A29188%2FScripts%2Fangular.min.js%3A38%3A188%0An%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A29188%2FScripts%2Fangular.min.js%3A7%3A331%0Ag%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A29188%2FScripts%2Fangular.min.js%3A37%3A488%0Aeb%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A29188%2FScripts%2Fangular.min.js%3A41%3A249%0Ayc%2Fc%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A29188%2FScripts%2Fangular.min.js%3A19%3A463%0Ayc%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A29188%2FScripts%2Fangular.min.js%3A20%3A274%0AZd%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A29188%2FScripts%2Fangular.min.js%3A19%3A83%0A%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A29188%2FScripts%2Fangular.min.js%3A294%3A192%0Ab%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A29188%2FScripts%2Fangular.min.js%3A175%3A62%0AIf%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A29188%2FScripts%2Fangular.min.js%3A35%3A365%0AHf%2Fd%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A29188%2FScripts%2Fangular.min.js%3A35%3A314%0A
 angular.min.js:6:416
```

Comment: Have you created the "newTopicController?"  Are you getting any error messages in the JavaScript console?

Comment: @DaveKaye no i don't create it ,

Comment: Right so when you try to go to that route you should be getting an error that Angular can't find the controller.

Comment: @DaveKaye when i click on it i don't get any error just the #/newmessage is added to the url and the page is still remain

Comment: So the error would not show on the page but in the JavaScript console.  That's what you mean, yes?

Comment: @DaveKaye i got this error in the console :Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.8/$injector/modulerr?...I update the post

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100180/discussion-between-ehsan-akbar-and-dave-kaye).

Comment: Sorry, missed the chat.  So two things.  1) My guess is still that it's looking for that missing controller.  2) If you work with the full and not minimized Angular you get (slightly) more comprehensive error messages.

Comment: @DaveKaye No problem ,i added the angularjs library from the google hosted so now i don't have any error but the page i mean newtopicview doesn't appear ?\

Answer (score 0):

Ehsan, I think you need a controller called newTopicController.  As you specify in your route:

```
$routeProvider.when("/newmessage", {
    controller: "newTopicController",
    templateUrl: "/templates/newTopicView.html"
});
```

When Angular goes to that route it's gonna look for both that controller and that template.  Try declaring even an empty one:

```
.controller('newTopicController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
   //empty
}]);
```